# How can I install mysql on an angstrom distribution?

Tags: mysql, angstrom

I tried using a different distribution (debian) but the rest of my application did not work. I've tried opkg install mysql-client and opkg install mysql-server however I get the error Unknown package for both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `opkg install mysql5`? If that works it looks like you will have to do some work to get the init scripts working properly:

http://arobenko-tech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/install-mysql-on-beagleboardbeaglebone.html

Comment: This does not work either. The same error message `Unknown package` appears.

Comment: However opkg download mysql5 followed by opkg install mysql5 and then followed by the link you posted above result in me being unable to log in. So either the supposed fix was not substantial or something else has gone very wrong...

Comment: When you say unable to login is that to a shell, or to mysql? If it is the latter, do you get any errors (either on the command line or in your syslog)? These may help diagnose the issue. Is mysqld actually running?

Comment: I cannot ssh onto the beaglebone nor can I connect to it via 192.168.7.2 in google chrome's address bar.